# Using Chi-squared Tests for Feature Selection with Big Data?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, chi-squared

When dealing with non-linear data, since the reliability of chi-squared tests diminishes with the number of samples, is it reasonable to divide a large dataset into sample spaces of, say, 20 or 40, calculate chi-squared and the associated probabilities on each sample space and then average the resulting probabilities together? Having an averaged probability for each feature, can one then select the features appropriately?

My logic is that since the data is non-linear, the data is not related across samples, only within a sample. Is my assumption correct?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "the reliability of chi-squared tests diminishes with the number of samples"?

Comment: I am coming at it from a machine learning perspective. My understanding is that as the degrees of freedom increase, the chi-squared tests preform worse. With big data, of say, a million rows, I suspect it's worthless. Since the data is not related from row to row, I was thinking of chunking them into groups of 40 and performing chi-square on each group. Then average all the values of the groups together. However, I have not found that solution mentioned anywhere, so I'm suspect of my logic.

Comment: The chi-square test of what?  Worse in what way? If you had a million rows, you are likely to get your chi-square test saying "statistically significant" - is that a bad thing?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I've been modeling chi-squared distribution. A few machine learning books state that the reliability of chi-squared falters as datasets grow. By inspecting the distribution curve, it makes sense -- it changes greatly. I cannot find the quotes in the books at the moment, but this on-line article mentions "chi square ... may give misleading results as sample size grows.":  https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-chi-square-test-in-evaluating-predictions-486404dd5bc. My solution: Batch the data in groups of 100 and average the results of each. Will it work?

Comment: The power of a chi-squared test (the ability to spot that there is a difference between  expected frequencies and observed frequencies when there is indeed a difference) increases with the amount of data.  I suspect the issue being mentioned is that with large amounts of data it may spot actual small differences which you might see as not large enough to worry about.  That is an argument against hypothesis testing and $p$-values in general (instead use confidence intervals or Bayesian methods) rather than against a chi-squared test.  Your suggestion would not help.

Comment: Ah, thank you, Henry. I hate to impose on your good nature too much, but do you know where I could find deeper-level treatments of these statistical ideas? Specifically, the reasoning and derivation? I find so many books, but they all seem to be instruction manuals, without the why, or at least only surface. Even the advanced texts, while compressing the material and using advanced notation, don't explain what Helmert/Pearson were thinking, or what you just pointed out. (I'm a little new to Stack Exchange and was going to contact you offline, but I don't see how.)

Comment: Found my reference. Good ol' Wikipedia and lots of clicking around. Guess it was too obvious. Thanks again.